# pylons/paste config files in fastcgi (deployment)

Tags: deployment, apache2, pylons, fastcgi, paster

I'm running a pylons app using fastcgi and apache2.  There are two versions (different revisions from my svn repo), one for staging and one for production.  I'd like them to use different paste config files.

Right now, my dispatch.fcgi inside htdocs in the pylons app just uses one config file (so both stage and live use the same configuration).  I'd like to be able to have debugging enabled on the stage server but not on the live server, for example.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to have more than one dispatch.fcgi prepared (referencing different INI files), then run a script on deployment to copy the correct one into the active position.

Another approach would be to have two .fcgi files, then use an IfDefine directive to select the proper rules in your main httpd.conf.

In other words, on the staging server, you start httpd with `httpd -D staging`, then put the staging config inside `<IfDefine staging></IfDefine>` and the other config inside `<IfDefine !staging></IfDefine>`

The limitation of this approach is that since IfDefine is binary, going past two options while still having a "default" option requires a bunch of extra lines. It's not the end of the world, and if you require a parameter to be given on all deployments it stays clean.

Still, I would use option #1.